# How to authenticate client on erlang cowboy websocket?

Tags: erlang, cowboy

We have used Erlang/Cowboy to develop a simple chatting service based on WebSockets. Right now, We are using localhost:8080 to connect server.
I want to do user authentication, that will be done based on the URL parameter, and it will return user id or none for the connection.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Before the websocket exchange, you can ask a token to your application and use it with your websocket client.